# Why my custom control do not work correctly?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I create a custom control for a custom button,here is its class:

```
public class SButton : Button
    {
        static SButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SButton)));
        }

        public Brush PressBackground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(PressBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PressBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PressBackground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PressBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PressBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(SButton), null);


    }
```

And here is Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SealBase">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SButton}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="B">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="B" Value="{Binding PressBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I used the SButton in XAML like this:

```
<CustomControl:SButton PressBackground="Black" Background="Red" Content="555" Foreground="White"/>
```

The custom control worked without error,but when I pressed it,the color do not change to black.

What's the matter with this?Would you please help me?Thank you.

Comment: Tried Value="{TemplateBinding PressBackground}"??

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota no,it report an error that System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException which is the style value error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TemplateBinding` is limited and doesn't work in template triggers. The alternative is to use `TemplatedParent` relative source

```
Value="{Binding PressBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Comment: Well,it works,it seems the problem is the RelativeSource.Thank you.